# If $\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_k$ bounded and $(b_k)$ is decreasing with $\lim_{k\to \infty}b_k=0$, then $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kb_k$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing, cauchy-sequences, upper-lower-bounds

Define $S_N:=\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_k$, which is bounded. Let $(b_k)$ the decreasing sequence such that $\lim_{k\to \infty}b_k=0$. Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kb_k$ converges.

I would like to have a feedback on my proof, please.

*Proof.*

Let $M>0$. As $\lim_{k\to \infty}b_k=0$, we have by definition that $\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists n_0 \ \forall k\ge n_0$: $|b_k|<\epsilon/M$.

Then, as $S_N$ is bounded we have that $|S_N|\le M$ $\forall k$ such that $1\le k\le N$.

Suppose by absurd that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kb_k$ diverges and so is not Cauchy:

$\exists \epsilon>0 \ \forall R \ \exists N \ge R$:

$|\sum_{k=R}^{N}a_kb_k|>\epsilon$.

But,

$|\sum_{k=R}^{N}a_kb_k|\le |\frac{\epsilon}{M}\sum_{k=R}^{N}a_k|\le  \epsilon$. Contradiction. Therefore $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kb_k$ converges.

I doubt a little bit that it holds... It appears to me strange that i did't use the hypithesis that $(b_k)$ is decreasing. I think if we use this hypothesis, we obtain that: $0<b_{k+1}<b_k$ $\forall k\in \mathbf{N}$. But as i work with absolute values, i don't really understand where it could help me.

Moreover i think in my final inequality with the sum i should have decomposed it in the difference between two sums to be more rigorous... Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: The problem is that you only know that $S_N$ is bounded, but the sum you estimate is not of that type.

Comment: @Severin Schraven So should I have evaluated the following: $|\epsilon/M \sum_{k=1}^{N}a_k-\sum_{k=1}^{R-1}a_k|$ ? Then bound $\sum_{k=1}^{N}$ by $M$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{R-1}a_k$ by $L:=\max\{x_k:1 \le k \le R-1\}$

Comment: In fact if you drop the decreasing condition, the statement is false. Pick $a_n=(-1)^n/n$ and $b_{2n+1}=0$, $b_{2n}$ converging sufficiently slow. For example $$b_{2n}= \left( \sum_{j=1}^n 1/j \right)^{-1/2}. $$

Comment: @Severin Schraven Hm.. With your example i see that it couldn't hold. But, if i bound everything as i have written in the previous comment, and pick $|b_k|<\frac{\epsilon}{M-L}$  it should work... But here i have to use the fact that $0<b_k$ as i don't know if $M>L$ or not. So ye i have to apply the fact that $b_n$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$. Does it hold this way?

Comment: You cannot really do that as you know nothing about the sign of the $a$'s.

Comment: As @SeverinSchraven points out, you cannot write $$|\sum_{k=R}^{N}a_kb_k|\le |\frac{\epsilon}{M}\sum_{k=R}^{N}a_k|$$ if you have no information about the sign of the $a_k$'s. If some are negative and some are positive, the bound is not correct.

Comment: @Clement C. I don't really see why it would be false... If you could provide an example i would really appreciate it!

Comment: Pick $N=2, R=1$ and $a_1=1, a_2=-1$. Then the RHS is zero, but depending on the coefficients $b$, the LHS might be positive.

Comment: @Severin Schraven Right, thank you very much for an explication.

Comment: This is the Dirichlet test.  It can be proved using summation by parts, where  $\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m a_kb_k\right| = \left|S_mb_m - S_nb_{n+1} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1}S_k(b_k- b_{k+1})\right|$ With $|S_n| \leqslant S$, show that $\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m a_kb_k\right|  \leqslant 2Sb_{n+1}$. That will use $b_k \geqslant b_{k+1}$.

Comment: @RRL Indeed, but the question is explicitly about whether the OP's proof is correct, not about whether the statement can be proven by other means.

Comment: @ClementC. Obviously -- that is why I am not posting an answer.  If OP does not want more information to move on then this comment can be ignored.

Comment: @Clement C. I think it is a little bit too late for this topic, but I just have a question please. Would it be correct to bound as the following:
$|\sum_{k=R}^{N}a_kb_k|\le \sum_{k=R}^{N} |a_kb_k|\le \epsilon/M \sum_{k=R}^{N}|a_k|$?

Thank you in advance for an answer

Comment: Depends on the last absolute value is (it's missing in your comment). If the last is $\sum_{k=R}^N |a_k|$, then the inequality is correct; but where do you go from there? You don't have any assumption on boundedness on the sum of the *absolute values* of $a_k$. @Daniil

Comment: Yes, i see that it doesn't help me too much to continue, but i just wanted to know if in general case this type of inequality holds as i checked with some examples and it appeared me working x) Thank you very much for an answer!

Comment: No problem! @Daniil